# Template Inheritance In Apache Server

Tags: django, html, apache, templates

How can I inherit the templates in Apache server as same as we can do in Django framework?

I want to inherit the some common tag's in all html files , by extending base.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes). This [reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html) in the Apache docs explains how to set it up.

---

If you want to use templates for inheritance and then generate a static site (all pages from the templates) that can run on Apache without any other requirements; use a static site generator.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/2254924) has a large list of them.

Static site generators have templates and a few command line scripts. You develop your site using templates. Once you are done, you enter a command and then all the .html files for your site are generated. You can then put these up on any server without any additional requirements.

Comment: Thank You for your response Burhan.I gonna through SSI, in that am not getting my solution there. Exactly I want to drive all child html pages with single parent html page.

Comment: How can I inherit the contents of one template to another (like extending a class) and change blocks of content therein.....?